# How to enable simple CORS on nginx

Tags: nginx, cors, mpeg-dash, dash.js

I installed Nginx on my laptop. My web server contains DASH streaming on-demand using the dash.js player which only hosted on localhost. I want to restrict only DASH dataset from localhost that can be used in that player. Can I use CORS for my purpose? I tried adding

```
location /{
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://localhost';
 }
```

but still any DASH dataset can still use the player which hosted on localhost. How to enable simple CORS features on Nginx? Is my understanding about CORS is wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I want to restrict only DASH dataset from localhost that can be used in that player. Can I use CORS for my purpose?

Not really.  CORS is used for getting at resources cross-domain.  If a player can natively play DASH (which none of the browsers do currently), then the content will play on any page, CORS support or not.  The way DASH players work in-browser today is by loading the resources via XHR requests and sending the data with the media source extension API.  To do this, the CORS headers are needed.

Cross-origin request blocking isn't really meant to prevent access to a resource.  It's to prevent scripts on one page from accessing resources belonging to another page, effectively impersonating a user.  `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers enable other pages to access those resources by effectively saying that the resource queried is safe for use.

If you want to actually block access to something, you should use `allow`/`deny`.  http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html